# Set a selection of text to bold inside a RichTextBox

Tags: report, ms-access-2007, richtextbox, selection

In an MS-Access RichTextBox on a Report, I want to make a selection of the text bold.

I found [this post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?286226-bold-in-a-label-%28resolved%29&p=1669027&viewfull=1#post1669027) on a forum which explains how to do this in VB6. I tried the same in MS-Access, both with a normal Access textbox with the `Text Format` property set to `Rich Text` and a `Microsoft Forms 2.0 TextBox` added via the `ActiveX Controls` dialogue box, neither works.

I know VBA is based heavily on VB6 so my logic is if it can be done in VB6, I should be able to do it in Access.

Am I right? Is it possible to set a selection of text to bold inside a RichTextBox on MS-Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not mention the version of Access, for 2007 (AFAIK) and 2010, you can create a textbox and set the Text Format on the data tab to Rich Text. You can then set the Control Source to:

```
="The quick <b>brown</b> fox"
```

In table design, the memo data type has a Rich Text option.

---

From [Rich formatted text that includes data from fields](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2008/01/16/rich-formatted-text-that-includes-data-from-fields.aspx)

> For a number of reasons the rich text control doesn't support the
>   full range of HTML but rather a limited subset of HTML focused around
>   formatting text. If you stick to the list of HTML tags and attributes
>   below you should be safe:

```
<font face="Arial Black" size=3 color="#A5A5A5" style="Background-Color:#FFFF00"> 
<strong> 
<em> 
<u> 
<br> 
<div align=right dir=RTL> 
<blockquote> 
<ol> and <li> for number 
<ul> and <li> for bulleted lists
```

Comment: Apologies, I have re-tagged the question. I am indeed using 2007 and this helps a lot, thankyou!

Comment: As a followup, do you know where I could find a list of supported tags for a RichTextBox in MS-Access? I have found [this](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ARNET3/ar3conSupportedHtmlTagsInRichText.html) but it seems to be .Net focused? Or to put it another way, can I use the <img> tag?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but I very much doubt it.

Comment: Blast! I take it I wouldn't be able to place an OLE object in there either?

Comment: Sadly, no. What are you trying to do? Would a webcontrol suit?

Comment: I am setting up a letter with a signature as an image, the location of the image changes based on how long the address is, but I have worked it out now, I just allowed myself enough whitespace so the image looks right regardless of the address length, thankyou for the help!