# change font of a selected part of textbox data not all textbox data?

Tags: ms-access-2010

i have form in access 2010 in this form i have textbox i want to use two different fonts for this textbox i take fonts on the for by two radio buttons ... when i select a part of textbox text and i click the radio button font i want to change the font of the selected part of text not all text ... i use this code to give the textbox different font but it make all textbox text the different font not a selected part

Private Sub Option84_GotFocus()
Me.Text15.FontName = "Ali_A_Sahifa Bold"
End Sub

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561633/set-a-selection-of-text-to-bold-inside-a-richtextbox/12561849#12561849

Comment: thank you but this no helpfull for me